# Can't connect to SQLite database through Gino (async sqlalchemy wrapper)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I was following the documentation for Gino (an asynchronous sqlalchemy wrapper), and when I just try to connect to an sqlite database, I get an error. Here's the code:

```
db = Gino()


class Server(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'servers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(), default='noname')


async def main():
    await db.set_bind('sqlite:///:memory:')
    await db.gino.create_all()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Here's the error:

```
AttributeError: 'SQLiteDialect_pysqlite' object has no attribute 'init_pool'
```

Does this mean for sure that Gino does not support the use of an SQLite database, or could something else be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right at the top of their `README`:

> Now (early 2018) GINO supports only one dialect asyncpg.

Granted, it's now early 2019, but that doesn't look to have changed:

```sh
├── gino
│   ├── dialects
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── asyncpg.py
│   │   └── base.py
```

In `asyncpg.py` they import `PGDialect` from sqlalchemy and extend from that to make a class called `AsyncPGDialect` which defines the `init_pool` method.

Comment: Alright thank you :) I wasn't sure if that was referring to raw sql queries or just support in general. I created a db in postgres and tried to link it that way, but I get an error for that too. I get a different error this time, but it doesn't seem to be related to gino. In case you're aware of what's going wrong, here it is `asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidPasswordError: password authentication failed for user "(my host username)"`. Otherwise I'll look elsewhere or ask a new question. 
Thanks a bunch either way :)